# FluentAssertions Should().BeEquivalentTo() fails with Lists containing run-time specified types deriving from identical interface

Tags: c#, xunit, fluent-assertions

I have the following test illustrating a simple example of what im attempting to achieve (comparison of two equivalent lists):

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var list1 = new List<IDomainEvent> { new BusinessCreatedDomainEvent { Name = "Microsoft" } };
    var list2 = new List<IDomainEvent> { new BusinessCreatedDomainEvent { Name = "Microsoft" } };

    // Act

    // Assert
    list1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(list2);
}
```

Ideally, each list should be able to contain any number of items of different types deriving from the `IDomainEvent` interface. The test currently fails. I'm suspecting it has something to do with `Should().BeEquivalentTo` not being fit to compare run-time specified types. How do i configure this example, so that the test passes?

Currently the test results are:

```
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Error] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7909767]     BusinessWrite.UnitTests.Infrastructure.EventStoreUnitTests.Test [FAIL]
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7922005]       System.InvalidOperationException : No members were found for comparison. Please specify some members to include in the comparison or choose a more meaningful assertion.
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7932461]       Stack Trace:
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7941986]         C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\FluentAssertions\Equivalency\GenericEnumerableEquivalencyStep.cs(74,0): at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.GenericEnumerableEquivalencyStep.Handle(IEquivalencyValidationContext context, IEquivalencyValidator parent, IEquivalencyAssertionOptions config)
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7945426]         C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\FluentAssertions\Equivalency\EquivalencyValidator.cs(85,0): at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyValidator.AssertEqualityUsing(IEquivalencyValidationContext context)
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7946187]         C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\FluentAssertions\Equivalency\EquivalencyValidator.cs(38,0): at FluentAssertions.Equivalency.EquivalencyValidator.AssertEquality(EquivalencyValidationContext context)
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7946610]         C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\FluentAssertions\Collections\CollectionAssertions.cs(394,0): at FluentAssertions.Collections.CollectionAssertions`2.BeEquivalentTo[TExpectation](IEnumerable`1 expectation, Func`2 config, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7947629]         C:\projects\fluentassertions-vf06b\Src\FluentAssertions\Collections\CollectionAssertions.cs(331,0): at FluentAssertions.Collections.CollectionAssertions`2.BeEquivalentTo[TExpectation](IEnumerable`1 expectation, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.7948569]         C:\Users\Christian\source\repos\unify\src\Services\Business\BusinessWrite\BusinessWrite.UnitTests\Infrastructure\EventStoreUnitTests.cs(43,0): at BusinessWrite.UnitTests.Infrastructure.EventStoreUnitTests.Test()
[8/14/2018 5:21:26 PM Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.8058517]   Finished:    BusinessWrite.UnitTests
```

Comment: Does `BusinessCreatedDomainEvent` override equals, etc.?

Comment: I came to this page only to realize I was using a wrong method to compare 2 lists. I needed to use `list1.Should().Equal(list2)` instead. Leaving it here just in case someone else has the same problem

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suspect that the interface `IDomainEvent` is without any `public` properties.
That explains the exception you're seeing, as the logic in `BeEquivalentTo()` uses the properties on `IDomainEvent` as the lists are of type `List<IDomainEvent>`.

To compare the two lists using the properties on `BusinessCreatedDomainEvent` instead, you can instead use

```
list1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(list2, options => options.RespectingRuntimeTypes());
```

From the [documentation](https://fluentassertions.com/documentation/#compile-time-types-vs-run-time-types)

> By default, Fluent Assertions respects an object’s or member’s declared (compile-time) type when selecting members to process during a recursive comparison. That is to say if the subject is a OrderDto but the variable it is assigned to has type Dto only the members defined by the latter class would be considered when comparing the object to the order variable. This behavior can be configured and you can choose to use run-time types if you prefer: